# Google Closure minifier online?

Tags: javascript, minify, google-closure

Has anyone setup an online copy/paste utility for **Google's Closure** minifier?

I'm working on a project and I want to minify part of the code manually without having to setup the entire project on my own.

Comment: Geuis, please check my answer. Was it helpful to you? If so, please check it as answered. TIA

Answer (score 95, accepted):

How about google's own service:
http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

I should point out that "setting up the entire project on my own" really is not half as scary as you make it out to be :p.

I mean, it's a matter of downloading a java.jar and running it. Instructions:

1. Download at http://closure-compiler.googlecode.com/files/compiler-latest.zip
2. Unzip
3. run java command line:

   `java -jar compiler.jar --js script-src.js --js_output_file script-compiled.js`

where `<compiler.jar>` is the full location to the `compiler.jar` file in the downloaded archive, `script-src.js` is the full filename of the source file, and `script-compiled.js` is the full filename of the result.

Comment: This is great. Thanks so much for setting this up.

Comment: Geuis, I didn't set it up. Google did.

Comment: @Ronald is this works same either download or do it online to minify js? I did online, size reduced but no improvement for page insight

Comment: ? Don't understand the question. You tried it and you are unhappy, try contacting Google.

Comment: Current link provided by Google is http://dl.google.com/closure-compiler/compiler-latest.zip

Comment: latest `closure-compiler-*.jar` is on [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.javascript/closure-compiler) > version (sample: v20200830) > files > jar

Answer (score 1):

Google offers the Closure Compiler via REST API, which you can invoke from a shell

https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_api

```
curl -v \
    -d code_url=http://server/js/file-big.js \
    -d compilation_level=ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS \
    -d output_info=compiled_code \
    -d output_format=text \
    http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/compile \
    > radix.min.js
```