# What minifier was used to generate the official JQuery "minified" version?

Tags: jquery

I need to edit the current JQuery library 1.4.x (and completely rename the JQuery "object/function") in a high conflicting environment.

My question is, with what minifier has the official JQuery minified version been generated. Where can I find this minifier? (As I want to use it for minifing my version too).

Thank you!
Tim

Answer (score 27, accepted):

According to the [offical release notes](http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14) it is the [Google Closure Compiler](http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/closure/compiler/).

UPDATE:

As of [jQuery 1.5](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/01/31/jquery-15-released/) they are using [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) [(ticket)](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7973) instead of the Google Closure Compiler.

Comment: This was true at least up to 1.4.3.  However, after that they stopped saying what they used to minify in their release notes.  Anyone know what they use now?  It doesn't seem formatted the same as closure compiler...

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention. I've updated my answer to reflect the changes the jQuery team has made to the build system.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is Google Closure: [Google Closure minifier online?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030671/google-closure-minifier-online)