# What type of minifier does JQuery use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, minify

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What minifier was used to generate the official JQuery “minified” version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207823/what-minifier-was-used-to-generate-the-official-jquery-minified-version)

Looking at their code it is minified alot better than mine.

I used Yahoo's Compressor.

But basically some/all the Javascript keywords are only used once..they are put into this structure

```
|documentGetElementById|anohter_one|.....|etc.
```

at the bottom of the minified source.

Yahoo's compressor did not do this.

How can I do this?

Comment: I've tried standard versions of uglify, closure, and compressor, none do it..it must be the way they configure it.

Comment: Very smart though..this is why I think it is O.K to write minified functions if you comment them...the comments come out at minification time but you get minifed code that would be otherwise missed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They use UglifyJS (ticket)

Hope I helped!